# Op amp CV amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

I've been trying to build a 9V sequencer for music and the CV (control voltage) on the output is very low, about 0.8V. I added a non-inverting amp (LM324) with a gain of 1:2 but all I get on the output is steady DC signal of 1.6V. The input signal is stepped voltage with a frequency of around 1Hz or less. Without the decoupling cap the output swings to the positive rail (8.5V). What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image: stepped voltage]

Comment: So, `signal in` is a bipolar signal (swinging higher and lower than the ground)? What are the supplies connected to the opamp? `I added a non-inverting amp with a gain of 1:2` your schematic shows a non inverting amplifier with a gain of four (1+ (3k/1k) ).

Comment: The TL072 is not a rail-to-rail opamp, so if you have the negative supply connected to ground, it simply can't handle that low-level input.

Comment: Thank you gents! The signal input is between 0 and 0.8V. Indeed, the resistor value in the schematics is wrong, it's supposed to be 1k. The supply is 0-9V DC while the virtual ground is from a TLE2425 rail splitter.

Comment: What rail splitter, I don't see it connected anywhere in the schematic. And what is the need for a splitter if your input is positive only (0-0.8v)?

Comment: This is why you need to supply a *complete* schematic of your setup. Which node in the diagram above is "virtual ground"? Is the "Signal In" relative to this virtual ground node?

Comment: @alkopop79 Let's try and figure out your situation. (1) Does the CV input share a common ground with your circuit, or is your circuit supplied by an independent floating ground e.g. a battery? (2) When you say CV is 0.8 Volts, what is this with reference to? Are there two lines coming from somewhere, one of them being ground of the source device, and the other the signal i.e. pulses of 0.8 Volts? (3) What do you mean by the *gain* of a voltage being low? Did you just mean the signal voltage is low? Because the only gain seems to be the op-amp circuit's gain shown.

Comment: @alkopop79 Ref. "*Without the decoupling cap the output swings to the positive rail (8.5V)*" That would most likely be the op amp going into latch-up. Consider switching to a rail-to-rail, unity-gain-stable op-amp with latch-up inhibition. Also, removing the decoupling capacitor is just a no-no.

Comment: @Anindo Ghosh Thank you for your help. (1) The circuits indeed share the same supply and ground. (3) Correct, it's the voltage too low. The op amp works with the signal as a buffer but once I build a non-inverting amplifier, there's no signal on the output. (2) Reference to the ground (0V).

Comment: @alkopop79 OK, so at the basic level, you would want to move over to an op-amp that supports input down to negative rail. Rail to Rail input op-amps are very common and inexpensive, there is no justification for using one that isn't. You won't need any virtual ground.

Comment: It would be better to edit your question and add there all the relevant info you have provided in the comments. You can't expect users reading the question to also read all the comments in order to find basic info about the described circuit.

Answer (score 2):

There is no DC path for the positive input of your op-amp. The positive input is connected to a base/gate that needs to draw a certain DC current, which is made impossible by C1. Put a resistor from the positive terminal to ground, which provides a DC path and forms a high pass filter with C1.

Answer (score -3):

Several problems:

The opamp needs to be powered properly, not both power pins connected to ground.

There needs to be a bypass cap accross power and ground close to the chip.  This should be low ESR, like a ceramic.  1-10 µF is a good range.

You have to actually **read the datasheet**.  If you had, you would have seen that the TL027 requires significant headroom from both power rails.  You can't expect it to work with signals near ground if the negative supply is also ground.

Comment: About the power pins being both connected to ground: Some schematics, especially from a couple of decades ago, used an upward-pointing (mirrored vertically) "ground" triangle symbol for indicating a supply rail. While this isn't common any more AFAIK, that's the symbol used in textbooks from when I was in college.

Comment: The power pins are obviously not both connected to the ground. I've tried the LM358 with similar results. The bypass cap is there on the breadboard. Any actual suggestions how to amplify the signal or improve the situation?

Comment: @Anindo: I am aware of the up-pointing triangle, but have also seen real ground symbols sometimes pointing upward, so there is no way to tell.  Since nothing is labeled, we don't know if this is bad drawing or bad power connections.

Comment: @alko: No, it's not obvious at all what exactly is connected to the power and ground pins.  The power connection, if any, isn't even labeled!  And no, there is no bypass cap there.  -1 for sloppily drawn schematic that you now say doesn't even match your real circuit.